# How to paginate post type of subcategory AJAX loop Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm pulling my hair over this. I'm working with the Sirius Wordpress theme. They have a loop where they paginate all portfolio pages. I only want it to display all portfolio pages within that subcategory, not all categories. Below is the pagination code. Thank you.

```
global $wp_query;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$pp_portfolio_items_page = 5;

$query_string = 'paged='.$paged.'&orderby=menu_order&order=ASC&post_type=portfolios&suppress_filters=0&posts_per_page='.$pp_portfolio_items_page;
if(!empty($term))
{
$query_string .= '&posts_per_page=-1&portfoliosets='.$term;
}
else
{
$query_string .= '&posts_per_page='.$pp_portfolio_items_page;
}
query_posts($query_string);
```

Comment: I tried doing query_posts($query_string.'&cat=-26'); and tried manipulating it that way to maybe exclude some categories. but to no avail, does nothing.

Comment: I figured this out. I had to find a work around if anyone wants to know. I basically categorized the portfolio posts by month and year. Below is an example of what I did. I believe since these are portfolio post types, i couldn't use categories, so I ended up using post date to help categorize.

Below is my query string

query_posts($query_string.'&year=2014&monthnum=01');

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I had to find a work around if anyone wants to know. I basically categorized the portfolio posts by month and year. Below is an example of what I did. I believe since these are portfolio post types, i couldn't use categories, so I ended up using post date to help categorize.

Below is my query string

query_posts($query_string.'&year=2014&monthnum=01');